# batch files finding specific files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

i am trying to get files from a directory and want to set names of the file to a variable using batch script.

this is my code .but it always setting same value to variable
 can any body give solution

```
echo on  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
for /f %%x in ('dir /b C:\backup_dir') do (  
SET test=%%~nx
if "%test:~0,6%"=="kdc_db" (set DUMP=%%x)  
if "%test:~0,6%"=="kdc_ke" (set KEYS=%%x)  
)  
echo %DUMP%  
echo %KEYS%
```

here dump and keys variables are always set to same value

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delayed expansion. You have already enabled it, you just need to replace your `%`'s with `!`'s

```
echo on  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
for /f %%x in ('dir /b C:\backup_dir') do (  
SET test=%%~nx
if "!test:~0,6!"=="kdc_db" (set DUMP=%%x)  
if "!test:~0,6!"=="kdc_ke" (set KEYS=%%x)  
)  
echo %DUMP%  
echo %KEYS%
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, the last two lines could be left unchanged, but modifying them as well should do no harm, of course.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Andriy, I wasn't sure so I put them in anyways as I didn't have time to test :)